# javascript numerical array

Tags: javascript

Hi all just wondering why the following code results in NaN?

```
function multiply(num1,num2){
    var total = num1 * num2;
    return total;
}

var numbers = Array(10,2);
var results = multiply(numbers);
alert (results);
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no automatic cast from array to 2 numbers.

Comment: @KaiMattern: `multiply.apply(null, numbers);`

Comment: Holy crap, that is cool. Thanks @grey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only passing one argument to `multiply`. Inside the function `num1` is an array and `num2` is undefined.

What you want to do is this,

```
var result = multiply(numbers[0], numbers[1]);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `.apply` to invoke the function.

```
var results = multiply.apply(null, numbers);
```

---

The `.apply` method invokes the `multiply` function, but accepts an Array or Array-like collection as the second argument, and sends the members of the collection as individual arguments.

FYI, the first argument to `.apply` sets the calling context. I passed `null` since your function makes no use of `this`.

This technique is especially useful if you decide to have your `multiply` function take a variable number of arguments. Using `.apply`, it won't matter how many are in the Array. They will be passed as individuals.

Answer (score 1):

you are passing an array into multiply where multiply expects 2 numbers.

when you try to multiply an array it makes sense that the result is NaN which stands for Not a number.

try:

```
var results = multiply(numbers[0], numbers[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling array values, you must define the value in the array.

For example:

```
var numbers = Array(10, 2)
```

JavaScript starts the array count at 0, so `numbers[0]` would be equal to 10 and `numbers[1]` would be equal to 2.

Comment: this doesn't really answer the problem. The issue is with the method of calling the function multiply not that the OP isn't defining the array as you mention.